# numpy broadcast from first dimension

Tags: python, numpy

In NumPy, is there an *easy* way to broadcast two arrays of dimensions e.g. `(x,y)` and `(x,y,z)`? NumPy broadcasting typically matches dimensions from the last dimension, so usual broadcasting will not work (it would require the first array to have dimension `(y,z)`).

Background: I'm working with images, some of which are RGB (shape `(h,w,3)`) and some of which are grayscale (shape `(h,w)`). I generate alpha masks of shape `(h,w)`, and I want to apply the mask to the image via `mask * im`. This doesn't work because of the above-mentioned problem, so I end up having to do e.g.

```
mask = mask.reshape(mask.shape + (1,) * (len(im.shape) - len(mask.shape)))
```

which is ugly. Other parts of the code do operations with vectors and matrices, which also run into the same issue: it fails trying to execute `m + v` where `m` has shape  `(x,y)` and `v` has shape `(x,)`. It's possible to use e.g. `atleast_3d`, but then I have to remember how many dimensions I actually wanted.

Comment: still useful after n years (I'm using your ugly way)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

how about use transpose:

```
(a.T + c.T).T
```

Comment: A bit cryptic for my taste.

Comment: This answer is unclear.  The symbols `a` and `c` do not appear in the question.  This needs more explanation.

Comment: numpy broadcasts automatically if first dimension is the trouble maker i.e
(y, z) @ (x, y, z) would be broadcasted to (x, y, z) @ (x, y, z).
But since the first array is (x, y) and not (y, z), the last dimension must be broadcasted, but numpy is not doing this.
Thus, we take the transpose that results in:
(y, x) @ (z, y, x) = (z, y, x) 
and transpose it back again:
(x, y, z)
Best greetings

Answer (score 5):

`numpy` functions often have blocks of code that check dimensions, reshape arrays into compatible shapes, all before getting down to the core business of adding or multiplying.  They may reshape the output to match the inputs.  So there is nothing wrong with rolling your own that do similar manipulations.

Don't offhand dismiss the idea of rotating the variable `3` dimension to the start of the dimensions.  Doing so takes advantage of the fact that `numpy` automatically adds dimensions at the start.

For element by element multiplication, `einsum` is quite powerful.

```
np.einsum('ij...,ij...->ij...',im,mask)
```

will handle cases where `im` and `mask` are any mix of 2 or 3 dimensions (assuming the 1st 2 are always compatible.  Unfortunately this does not generalize to addition or other operations.

A while back I simulated `einsum` with a pure Python version.  For that I used `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` and `np.nditer`.  Look into those functions if you want more power in mixing and matching dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

as another angle: if you encounter this pattern frequently, it may be useful to create a utility function to enforce right-broadcasting:

```
def right_broadcasting(arr, target):
    return arr.reshape(arr.shape + (1,) * (target.ndim - arr.ndim))
```

Although if there are only two types of input (already having 3 dims or having only 2), id say the single if statement is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing with np.newaxis creates a new axis in that place. Ie

```
xyz = #some 3d array
xy = #some 2d array
xyz_sum = xyz + xy[:,:,np.newaxis]
or
xyz_sum = xyz + xy[:,:,None]
```

Indexing in this way creates an axis with shape 1 and stride 0 in this location.

Comment: Yes, but I still have to condition on whether the target has 2 or 3 axes. (I actually tried this initially, and it failed spectacularly with grayscale images, allocating 1024*1024*1024-sized arrays and blowing up my memory)

Comment: In such a situation, id put a line in front of the relevant code to 'upcast' arrays with too low dimensionality to the correct broadcasting patterns; like arr = arr if arr.ndim==3 else arr[...,None]. Its still an extra line of code, but I don't think you can avoid that, and at least its more human-readable than the reshape based solution.

Comment: You should try to understand why it produced `1024*1024*1024` before rejecting this approach out of hand.  My guess is it was trying to do `yz[None,:,:]+xy[:,:,None]` where dimensions were `1024`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just decorate-process-undecorate:

```
def flipflop(func):
    def wrapper(a, mask):
        if len(a.shape) == 3:
            mask = mask[..., None]
        b = func(a, mask)
        return np.squeeze(b)
    return wrapper

@flipflop
def f(x, mask):
    return x * mask
```

Then

```
>>> N = 12
>>> gs = np.random.random((N, N))
>>> rgb = np.random.random((N, N, 3))
>>> 
>>> mask = np.ones((N, N))
>>> 
>>> f(gs, mask).shape
(12, 12)
>>> f(rgb, mask).shape
(12, 12, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy, you just add a singleton dimension at the end of the smaller array. For example, if xyz_array has shape (x,y,z) and xy_array has shape (x,y), you can do

```
xyz_array + np.expand_dims(xy_array, xy_array.ndim)
```